# Do i need to do db.logout() before changing another db password in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, go, drive, mongo-go-driver

consider i have two database in mongoDB say db1 and db2 i want to change the password for both initially , do i need to logout db1 before changing db2 password ? or that is not required ? what's the best practice?

current sequence

```
conn, err := mongo.connect(ctx, connOpts)

//then update the db pass
cmd := bson.D{{"updateUser", dbUserName}, {"pwd", newPass}}
err = client.Database(db1).RunCommand(context.TODO(), command, opts).Decode(&result)

//then logout
err = client.Database(db1).RunCommand(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"logout", 1}}, opts).Decode(&result)


//repeat the same steps again for changing the db2 password
```

Am I following the right sequence ? whether connecting the db once is enough to do both operation ? is login and logout really required here ?

I'm using go mongo driver .

Comment: You have the code. What happened when you ran it?

Comment: @icza actually i see a weird problem , Sometimes it fails to login into db2 and fails to change the password , sometimes it passes . Not sure whether am i running into race condition here . The error that i get during failure is : 

`connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.`

Comment: Instead of logoff and connect again, you can also switch user as by  `db.getSiblingDB('admin').auth('username', 'secret')` But I don't know, it this command is available in go.